# CollectionUtils in java using predicate

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons, apache-commons-collection

I have a `List<Object>` and I want to return the first value that it finds true which matches a predicate.

I found that I can use `CollectionUtils.find(collection,predicate)` (Apache commons). Assuming that the `Object` contains a integer variable called : `value` , how do i specify in the predicate that the value can be `1,2,3,4,5` and to discard those that dont match. Is it possible to do 'contains'.

Also not using java 8 so unable to do stream.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To return the first element in the list which matches the given predicate:

```
MyObject res = CollectionUtils.find(myList, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(MyObject o) {
        return o.getValue() >= 1 && o.getValue() <= 5;
    }
});
```

To filter the list so that it only contains elements matching the predicate:

```
CollectionUtils.filter(myList, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(MyObject o) {
        return o.getValue() >= 1 && o.getValue() <= 5;
    }
});
```

You can notice that the `Predicate<MyObject>` is the same.

Comment: I thought th OP wanted to filter the list (`discard those that dont match`). You are just finding the first object matching the predicate.

Comment: Worth noting that the generic `Predicate` is only present in version 4

Comment: No you are right, I am using the find because I want to return the first value that it matches. Thank you

Comment: What should the predicate be? since i am getting The type Predicate is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <MyObject>.

Comment: So you need to cast the ``Object`` to its actual type, the one that contains the ``value`` variable

Comment: Yeah have tried that but still doesnt work, same error.

Comment: It is the same issue : Predicate is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <MyObject> . Seems to be because I am using collections, it is using the predicate from that instead of the default predicate that does allow parameters. Is there a way around this without passing a parameter?

Comment: ``MyObject`` must be replaced by the type of the elements contains in your list, the type that contains the ``value`` variable.

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8 you can write

```
Optional<Integer> found = list.stream().filter(i -> i >= 1 && i <= 5).findAny();
```

Before Java 7 the simplest solution is to use a loop.

```
Integer found = null;
for(integer i : list)
   if (i >= 1 && i <= 5) {
        found = i;
        break;
   }
```

This would be the cleanest and fastest way as Java 7 doesn't have support for lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.removeIf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) (I'm assuming you are using JDK 8). You can also use a Stream :

```
list = list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using Apach Commons Collections, you can use [CollectionUtils.filter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html).

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not, which is why I chose to use CollectionUtils.